# Why height percentage has no effect?

Tags: html, css

I have a html code where I am trying to change height with percentage. But it is not working and I am getting same sizes from three different  tags.

This is the code:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:40%; height:60%">

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:40%; height:10%">

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:40%; height:20%">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a percentage value in `height` property, it is calculated with respect to th height of its containing block.

However, if the height of its containing block depends on the content, it would be a circular reference.

Therefore, in that case, the percentage computes to `auto`.

This is explained in the spec:

> [**10.5 Content height: the 'height' property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property)
>
> **<percentage>**
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block). If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

Then, you can fix it setting an explicit height to the containing block.

```css
div {
  height: 200px; /* explicit height */
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
img {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10%;
}
img:first-child {
  height: 60%;
}
img:last-child {
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Favicon">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Favicon">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Favicon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline elements where height is set by line height and inline boxes. To do what you show, you need to make the elements block level or inline-block where the height property can take effect.

Comment: That's true for [most inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced). However, it's false for [replaced inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height), like images.

Comment: @Oriol which is what I said.